# Pass Variables to Project Parameters in SSIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, parameters, ssis, parameter-passing

I am new to this network. Hoping I'll find an answer to this problem.

I have a SSIS Project with multiple Packages which are using the Project Parameters. I am trying to update the Project Parameters e.g. @PeriodStart: 2014-05-31. I can't find a way to dynamically write to the Project Parameter.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 in 4.0 Framework. Please can anyone shed light on this ?!

Kind Regards
Bal

Comment: Can you provide some code showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried in the Project.Params area found in the Solution Explorer to use the Parameters but didn't work out unless there is something I'm doing wrong. I have also come across catalog.set_object_parameter_value but not sure what the correct syntax is to use this.

Comment: I believe catalog.set_object_parameter_value  is used in SQL however

Comment: *How* are you calling your packages? Are you trying to do this all within the .NET object model? Are you deploying to SQL Server, assuming Project deployment model? We need more information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Project parameters are read only. What you are after is to assign variables depending on the project parameters and then read the variables. An overview of variables and parameters is here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22194.use-ssis-variables-and-parameters-in-a-script-task.aspx

For example, you could add a script task to the control flow and then read in the project parameters, assign a readwrite variable to the script task and then use this variable.

Comment: @billnkc I am doing this using a Script Task. In summary I am trying to change the Project Parameters at runtime i.e. change "@PeriodEnd" to the last working day. This will feed into all my Packages to run for the correct date.

Comment: If the Project.Params are read only then that has answered my question unless there is a way around it ?

Comment: I have tried this already: string MyPeriodEnd = "2014-07-31"; Dts.Variables["Project::PeriodEnd"].Value = MyPeriodEnd; This obviously fails as you cannot add the Prject.Params in the ReadWriteVariables found in the Script Task Editor.